# Possible to insert some text String into filter text area

Tags: smartgwt

I have a `ListGrid` and above each column of data, there is a filter box. I can manually some text in there and press Filter to filter. How can i insert some text into a filter box with some sort of method in the code? I want to get a filter box above a column, then insert a certain String text in it, so the user can just press the Filter button instead of typing it in themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow:

- Use `ListGrid.setShowFilterEditor(true)` to show the filter on grid
- Use `ListGridField.setFilterEditorProperties(textItem)` to show the filter on specific column

  For example:

  ```
  TextItem textItem = new TextItem();
  // set default value    
  listGridField.setFilterEditorProperties(textItem);
  ```
- Use `ListGrid.addFilterEditorSubmitHandler()` (if needed) to customize the filter editor submit request.

Follow the [SmartGWT showcase - Grid Sort Filter](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_sortfilter_filter)